# Oracle update on two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have two tables:

```
Item: Order_no, Item, Line_No
Fulfill: Order_no, Location, LINE NO
```

The LINE_NO field value is the same in both the tables for all the orders.

I want update the value of LINE_NO to start from 1 and going to the number of line items, in the both tables.

How do I do that ?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it in SQL - Guys please advise if I am missing something :) I would do it in a procedure (stored if this is a part of some processing) or in a script (if one-timer update only) and treat it as one transaction start with begin then update first table, update second table. after that if there's some error on any, just rollback the whole transaction or commit if it's okay. I can give you a quick example if you like to see how to do it...

Comment: This looks strange. Beginning with the table names. Item has an `order_no`? So each item can only be ordered once? Shouldn't his rather be an `order_position` table than an `item` table? Then as you have stored the order positions already, why would you suddenly change the line_numbers? And what sorting do you want applied when giving the number? Please show some sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a procedure it may look like that. It's only a skeleton but in general, you just need to put your updates inside begin - exception - end block (like you do try - catch - finally in Java):

```
create or replace procedure pr_procedure_name is
   --some declarations
   l_line_no  integer;
   l_order_no integer;
begin
   --some processing here
   begin

      update item i
         set i.line_no = l_line_no
       where i.order_no = l_order_no;

      update fulfill ff
         set ff.line_no = l_line_no
       where ff.order_no = l_order_no;

      --commit;
      --commit or not here - it depends on your processing

   exception
      when others then
         --log something?
         rollback;
   end;

   --some processing there

end pr_procedure_name;
```

Comment: I created a procedure similar to this one and it did the job!